# Jenkins pipeline cannot execute kubectl locally (with minikube)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, kubectl, minikube

## My scenario:

I have Jenkins running at http://localhost:8080, kubectl, minikube up and running

```
$ minikube status
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.100
```

I want so setup a simple Jenkins pipeline so that the kubernetes config files will be applied automatically. Here's the snippet of my pipeline:

```
stage('deploy'){
 sh ''' 
 kubectl apply -f .'''
    }
```

This error appears:

```
+ kubectl apply -f .
unable to recognize "myApp_deployment.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1"
unable to recognize "myApp_service.yaml": no matches for kind "Service" in version "v1"
```

I try changing `apps/v1` to `apps/v1beta1` but still no luck.

When I try checking kubectl version (also within jenkins pipeline), here's the output:

```
+ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:40:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Error from server (Forbidden): <html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fversion%3Ftimeout%3D32s'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fversion%3Ftimeout%3D32s');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
```

I can manually run those commands (open terminal, run in project directory) without problem.

How can I solve this?

Comment: How are you providing the Kube authentication to the Jenkins user in the pipeline code or GUI?